# Prove or disprove If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $K$

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$, then $H$ is a subgroup
of $K$

I claim this is true my attempt was that if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ then $a,b,ab^{-1} \in H,K$ Since $H$ is a subset of $K$ then every element of $H$ is in $K$ and it should hold that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ since $ab^{-1}$ is in $H$ whenever $a,b \in H$. Though I feel I might be missing something with the idea of the subset vs subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple really.

> $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, if  it's a subset that is a group in its own right, with the same operation as $G$.

So, if $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$, then by what is given, $H$ is a subset of $K$, and it's a group in its own right, with the same operation as $G$, and hence as $K$.

Therefore, $H$ is very much a subgroup of $K$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup).

> **Theorem (One-step Subgroup Test):** Let $S$ be a $\color{red}{\text{nonempty}}$ $\color{green}{\text{subset}}$ of a group $T$. Then $S\le T$ if and only if $\color{blue}{\text{for all }}\color{blue}{a,b\in S}\color{blue}{\text{ we have }ab^{-1}\in S}$.

Since $H\le G$, we have $e\in H$, so $\color{red}{H\neq\varnothing}$.

We are given $\color{green}{H\subseteq K}$.

Let $\color{blue}{x,y\in H}$. Then, since $H\le G$, we have $\color{blue}{xy^{-1}\in H}$.

But then $H\le K$.