# Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ subgroups of $G$ such that $K \subseteq H$. Is $K$ always a subgroup of $H$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ subgroups of $G$ such that $K \subseteq H$. Is $K$ always a subgroup of $H$?

My thought:

Yes, let $(G, \star)$ be the group. So we know that $K$ contains the neutral element as well, which is in $H$ too. Since it is a subgroup of $G$ it is closed under inverses as well. So it should be a subgroup of $H$ under the operation $\star$. But I'm not sure if there is a case where that will not hold.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've just added my thoughts on this.

Comment: It follows from the one-step subgroup test rather quickly.

Comment: [Here's a duplicate.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2433921/104041)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove or disprove If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433921/prove-or-disprove-if-h-and-k-are-subgroups-of-a-group-g-such-that-h-subs)