# Let $A,B\leqslant G $ s.t $ A \subseteq B$ then $A \leqslant B$

Tags: group-theory

Question: Let $A,B\leqslant G $ s.t $ A \subseteq B$ then $A \leqslant B$

Actually question looks like simple but I can not convince myself about proof that I did. Since $A,B\leqslant G $ then $a_1 a_2^{-1}\in A$ and $b_1 b_2 ^{-1} \in B$. Clearly, $a_1 a_2^{-1}\in B$ because $A$ is subset of $B$. This is all which I said. Can anyone confirm me?

Comment: This question was asked three times in the last days :)

Comment: Since $\;A\le G\;$ then $\;A\;$ is a group on its own, and it is thus a subgroup of any group (under the very same product operation as $\;A\;$ ...!) that contains $\;A\;$  as a subset.

Comment: sorry I didnt know that. Can you send link to me to read?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364234/let-g-be-a-group-and-h-k-subgroups-of-g-such-that-k-subseteq-h-is-k#comment9115268_4364234) is one link. There are others, so this seems to be some exam question.

Comment: I dont know you trust me or not but for me that is not.